# Fill missing array values with zero if an array is empty in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

i want to produce an array in this format [x,x,x] where each x is grouped by the addition of each retail id, however, for an empty array list, i want to have [x,x,0] assuming the third array is empty, instead of [x,x]

Below is my code

```
    <?php
$q = "SELECT DISTINCT outletid FROM " . TBL_SALES_LOGS;
$result = $database->query($q);
$outlets = [];
?>
data: [<?php
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    // $outletname = $row['title'];
    $outlet_id = $row['outletid'];
    $outlets[] = $row['outletid'];
    $amount = $row['amount'];
    ?>
    <?php echo $outlet_id; ?>,
<?php } ?> ]

data: [<?php
$outlet = implode("','", $outlets);
$qsum3 = "SELECT  outletid, SUM(amount) AS totalsum FROM " . TBL_SALES_LOGS . " WHERE outletid IN ('{$outlet}') and fueltype='PMS' group by `outletid`";
$qresult3 = $database->query($qsum3);
while ($rowq3 = $qresult3->fetch_assoc()) {
    $tot3 = $rowq3['totalsum'];
    ?>'<?php echo $tot3; ?>',<?php } ?>]
```

instead of having [3,4,2,3] and missing value not showing, i want to have [3,4,2,0,3] for the missing values, assuming 0 is the missing values

thanks

Comment: How do you know which order the missing value goes in if the DB returns just four results?

Comment: The order is grouped by outletid, summing up all the amount in itemid, so for missing outletid, it wot be listed in the array

Comment: Is `$outlets` an array of id's?

Comment: I have edited my code, that can answers your question, thanks so much

Comment: View answer below.

Comment: **WARNING**: This has some severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) because user data is used inside the query. Whenever possible use **prepared statements**. These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.
**NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or any user data directly in your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made a few changes. Mostly created a key value array depending on the id as the key, and setting all those values to sum => 0. Then, when you loop through all of the id and their sum's it changes the sum of the id's it finds.

It is untested, but should solve it. You may need to change the end. It was messy with all the opening and closing php tags.

```
<?php
$q = "SELECT DISTINCT outletid FROM " . TBL_SALES_LOGS;
$result = $database->query($q);
$outlets = [];
$outletsIdSum = [];
?>
data: [<?php
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    // $outletname = $row['title'];
    $outlet_id = $row['outletid'];
    $outlets[] = $outlet_id;
    $outletsIdSum[(int)$outlet_id] = 0;
    $amount = $row['amount'];
    ?>
    <?php echo $outlet_id; ?>,
<?php } ?> ]

data: [<?php
$outlet = implode("','", $outlets);
$qsum3 = "SELECT  outletid, SUM(amount) AS totalsum FROM " . TBL_SALES_LOGS . " WHERE outletid IN ('{$outlet}') and fueltype='PMS' group by `outletid`";
$qresult3 = $database->query($qsum3);
while ($rowq3 = $qresult3->fetch_assoc()) {
    $outletsIdSum[(int)$rowq3['outletid']] = $rowq3['totalsum'];
}
echo "'" . implode( "','", $outletsIdSum );
    ?>]
```

Answer (score -1):

add if condition on array

```
<?php
     foreach(some_array as a)
       {
      if(a=="" or a==NULL)
        a=0;
    }
?>
```

this will check array element which is empty and then ,if it is empty it will assign array element to '0'

use this algorithm

Comment: Please explain more

Comment: This is inaccurate to the request and not helpful. It cannot be used in the code shown above

Comment: let me explain   ,first you'll select data from database .table contains 5 columns ,if user inserted only 4 values.

Comment: now youll select row ,then check whether  the fetch column is empty or not t.if it is empty assign it to 0